# Mysql, заменить значения столбца на id из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

У меня такой вопрос: есть две таблицы - **"ученик"** и **"класс"**. В таблице "ученик" есть столбец `класс`, в котором сейчас такие данные: английский, немецкий, физический и т.д., т.е. данные непосредственно строковые.

В другой таблице "класс" есть одноименное поле `класс`, где такие же данные как в первой таблице (английский, немецкий, физический и т.д.). В таблице "класс" также есть поле `id`.

**Вопрос:** как заменить данные столбца класс таблицы "Ученик" соответствующими значениями `id` из второй таблицы?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
  `pupils` LEFT JOIN 
  `classes` ON `pupils`.`class` = `classes`.`class`
SET `pupils`.`class` = `classes`.`id`
```

В моём примере если вдруг в таблице "ученики" есть неправильные значения поля "класс", то есть не имеющие пары в "классы", то они будут переписаны значением NULL. Если хотите избежать этого и оставить плохие значения как есть, замените `LEFT JOIN` на просто `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
update `ученик`
   set `класс`=(select max(id) from `класс`
                 where `класс`.`класс`=`ученик`.`класс`)
 where exists(select 1 from `класс`
               where `класс`.`класс`=`ученик`.`класс`)
```

Условие where нужно, что бы не повредить текстовые данные, если в таблице `класс` не найдется подходящая запись.

Если требуется переписать все записи, вне зависимости от наличия записи в 'классе', то надо убрать условие where, тогда несуществующие названия будут заменены на NULL.

Comment: Возможно "повредить" будет лучшим вариантом. А так получается, что  строковые названия будут вперемешку с числовыми идентификаторами.

Comment: @artoodetoo Вот для этого я и упомянул про where, что бы человек мог сам выбрать, и убрать его, если ему вдруг нужны NULL.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, все ответы пригодились, так как главное что разобрался в задаче